# ListView throws UnhandledException when ScrollTo

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a simple page with a ListView like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="ListViewDemo.MainPage">

   <StackLayout>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Label Text="From" />
         <DatePicker x:Name="fromPicker" Grid.Row="1" />
         <Label Text="To" Grid.Column="1" />
         <DatePicker x:Name="toPicker" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
      </Grid>
      <ListView>
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout>
                     <Label Text="{Binding FromDate}" />
                     <Label Text="{Binding ToDate}" />
                  </StackLayout>
               </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
   </StackLayout>

 </ContentPage>
```

When the Date is changed I want to scroll to the Event, that is closest to the current Date, but I get an `UnhandledException` when I use `ScrollTo` on UWP, and iOS just do not scroll.

I was thinking of using ItemAppearing, but is it trustable, if I have enough events on the list?

If I use `await Task.Delay(500)` I do not get the `UnhandledException`, but instead the content jumps on my screen.

Is there any solution to this problem?

```
public void SetEvents(params CalenderEventDto[] events)
{
   var dateToScrollTo = DateTime.Now.Date;

   var scrollToEvent = events?.OrderBy(x => x.Start.Date)?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Start.Date >= dateToScrollTo  || c.End.Date >= dateToScrollTo );

   var orderedEvents = events.GroupBy(x => x.Start.Date).OrderBy(x => x.Key);

   _calendarEvents.Clear();

   foreach (var groupedEvents in orderedEvents)
   {
      foreach (var calendarEvent in groupedEvents)
      {
         _calendarEvents.Add(calendarEvent);
      }
   }

   //await Task.Delay(450);
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => lstCalendar.ScrollTo(scrollToEvent, ScrollToPosition.Start, false));
}
```

***EDIT***
I figured out, the problem is on iOS too

Comment: "Unhandled exception" just means you did not catch the exception - if you did it would probably provide a description of the problem.

Comment: I tried by surrounding it with a try-catch but without success.

Comment: Don't use `async void` unless really necessary. It's meant for events and event like methods. You cannot catch exceptions from an `async void` method. In fact, there is no async code at all so remove the `async` modifier or make it return a `Task` and you'll be able to catch the exception.

Comment: I added the catch inside the method (sorrunding the `ScrollTo`). The `async` was used, when I used `Task.Delay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, if I moved the `SetEvents` from the constructor to `OnAppearing` it works